# Class validator allow when undefined but not when null

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-validator

```
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(({ value }) => (value ? new Date(value) : null))
  @IsDate()
  doj: Date;
```

The above code works fine when `doj` is undefined. It has the same behavior when `doj` is also null.

However, I want the validation to pass when it is undefined and fail if null. How do I achieve this with class validator?

**EDIT:**

Based on the accepted answer, I made a function to validate and transform dates. This is for nestjs with graphql btw.

```
import { BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TransformFnParams } from 'class-transformer';
import * as moment from 'moment';

export const dateTransformValidate = (
  params: TransformFnParams & { nullable: boolean }
) => {
  const date = params.value;
  if (date == null) {
    if (params.nullable === false) {
      throw new BadRequestException(`Cannot remove ${params.key}.`);
    }
    return date;
  }
  const m = moment(date);
  if (m.isValid()) return date;
  throw new BadRequestException('Invalid date.');
};
```

Usage:

```
// allow undefined but not nulls
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform((params) => dateTransformValidate({ ...params, nullable: false }))
  dob: Date;

// allow undefined and null
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(dateTransformValidate)
  doj: Date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check out if doj is null and throw an Error

```
import { IsOptional, IsDate } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform, TransformFnParams, plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

function transformFn(params: TransformFnParams) {
    if (params.value == null) {
        throw new Error('value cannot be null')
    }
    return new Date(params.value)
}
class MyClass {
    @IsOptional()
    @Transform(transformFn) 
    @IsDate()
    doj: Date | undefined;    
}

//tests
let instance = plainToClass(MyClass, JSON.parse('{"doj": "2022-02-08T12:00:00Z"}'));
console.log(instance.doj, typeof instance.doj); //2022-02-08T12:00:00Z object

instance = plainToClass(MyClass, JSON.parse('{}'));
console.log(instance.doj); //undefined

instance = plainToClass(MyClass, JSON.parse('{"doj": null}'));
console.log(typeof instance.doj); //Error: 'value cannot be null'
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/typescript-playground-export-forked-kfkspt?file=%2Findex.ts%3A21%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsrocn7f00062v6n5wc5sp2j%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsrocn7f00022v6nd2nulrs9%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsrocn7f00032v6nrhzydc1i%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsrocn7f00052v6nbb6d9c0k%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsrocn7f00022v6nd2nulrs9%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsrocn7f00022v6nd2nulrs9%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsrohj9k00022v6mnacwyuvi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A21%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A21%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsrohj9k00022v6mnacwyuvi%2522%257D%252C%2522clsrocn7f00052v6nbb6d9c0k%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsrocn7f00042v6nenovvb6n%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsrocn7f00052v6nbb6d9c0k%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsrocn7f00042v6nenovvb6n%2522%257D%252C%2522clsrocn7f00032v6nrhzydc1i%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsrocn7f00032v6nrhzydc1i%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)